# How to connect gerrit ssh through HAproxy(LB)?

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, gerrit

I'm able to access our `gerrit` web from bare metal based `Kubernetes cluster` through an independent `HAProxy`(LB).

Currently i have below `HAproxy` configurations in `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` file to access cluster gerrit service.

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    default_backend gerrit-http

backend gerrit-http
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    balance roundrobin
    server Kworker1 192.168.1.11:80 check
    server Kworker2 192.168.1.12:80 check
    server Kworker3 192.168.1.13:80 check

frontend ssh-in
    bind *:29418
    mode tcp
    default_backend gerrit-ssh

backend gerrit-ssh
    mode tcp
    server Kworker1 192.168.1.11:29418 check
    server Kworker2 192.168.1.12:29418 check
    server Kworker3 192.168.1.13:29418 check
```

But when i tried to test the gerrit ssh connection using below command. it always fails

```
$ ssh -p 29418 user@gerrit.review.com
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

What is wrong with my haproxy configurations? how do i use gerrit ssh along with gerrit http in HAproxy(LB)?

Comment: Are you able to do ssh directly to the gerrit pods?

Comment: Asking this to ensure sshd is running

Comment: from host(worker) machine to pod?

Comment: I mean to `192.168.1.11:29418`, from the same machine running haproxy

Comment: From my HAproxy server to Kubernetes cluster gerrit service pod?

Comment: Yes. First ensure desired connectivity is working without haproxy LB, from HA proxy server to backends( pods/svc) . This is to ensure or eliminate haproxy involvement

Comment: Haproxy to Cluster host machines ssh works. However from HAproxy(LB) to K8s service ssh can you share an example command to verify it?